# Difference between dateformat() and createODBCDate() in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

What is the difference between `dateformat()` and `createODBCDate()` in ColdFusion? Are these two functions the same or not? When do I need to use `DateFormat()` and when do I need to use `createODBCDate()`?

Comment: What are you using it for? What is the problem? Adobe has info available on the interwebz. What have you searched for and not found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dateFormat()` accepts a date and a format 'mask' and returns a string of the date, in the format passed.

For example, consider the following code:

```
mydate = dateFormat( now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
```

Assuming the date is July 15, 2014 (which it was when I wrote this) the value of the variable named 'mydate' would be '2014-07-15' (without the quotes). So, you need to pass a date to the function.

`createODBCDate()` creates an actual date from the values passed - it does not format the date, it merely creates a date 'object'

`dateFormat()` is typically used to display a date in a user friendly manner. Try running this `writeDump( now() )` to see what the default display looks like.

`createODBCDate()` is typically used when you need to pass a date to a SQL query. However, if you use `cfqueryparam` with a cf_sql_type that accepts a date, ColdFusion will handle converting the value (assuming it is a valid date) to a date that the database accepts and you do not need to use `createODBCdate()`

In 10+ years of doing ColdFusion, I have *never* used `createODBCDate()`

Comment: Thank you Scott and Adam